# spring security dynamic roles to load from db

Tags: database, dynamic, spring-security, role

my question is similar to post [question]: [Dynamic Spring Security using SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381776/dynamic-spring-security-using-sql-query)

I've tried the solution given by Rob Winch but spring security complains as such. So not sure whether this due to spring latest version 3.1 or something else I've missed. Any guidance is much appreciated.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.xx.web.security.filter.JdbcFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since spring was complaining about DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource, solution was to extend that class as answered by jbbarquero here:
[How to dynamically decide <intercept-url> access attribute value in Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893061/how-to-dynamically-decide-intercept-url-access-attribute-value-in-spring-secur)

Comment: You may have been running into https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1957 that has since been fixed. This is hard to say without seeing a complete stack.