# Chained authentication in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-java-config

Can I chain multiple instances of `AuthenticationEntryPoint` in Spring Security 3.2.4?

I attempting to create the following scenario:

- A certain URL is secured with Spring Security
- The `AuthenticationEntryPoint` used is `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`
- An admin interface can spawn services under this URL
- The admin can choose to secure these services with `CLIENT-CERT`

When a user attempts to access the secure URL:

1. If the path has been secured with `CLIENT-CERT` then authentication fails unless they have provided a valid certificate the corresponds to a user in the `UserService`. Standard Spring Security `x509` authentication.
2. Once the user has been authentication as per the first point, or if the URL is not secured with `CLIENT-CERT`, they are directed to a `FORM` based authentication page.
3. Once they successfully authenticate with a username and password, they are directed to a landing page.

I am running on Tomcat 7.0.54 with `clientAuth="want"`. This works perfectly in a "simple" Spring Security set up - i.e. with one `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` set to `x509()` and another set to `formLogin()` as per [this example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity)

So, I want a process flow something like the following:

[image: Authentication flow]

I have had some success with dynamically changing the used authentication method by using a `DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint` but:

- When using an `AntPathRequestMatcher` to map, say, `/form/**` to a `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` the authentication servlet (`/j_spring_security_check`) gives a `HTTP404` error.
- When using an `AntPathRequestMatcher` to map, say, `/cert/**` to a `Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint` the user's details are not extracted from the presented client certificate so this gives a `HTTP403` error.

I also cannot see how to force a user to authenticate *twice*.

I am using the java-config and not XML.

My code:

I have a `DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint`:

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationEntryPoint delegatingEntryPoint() {
    final LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, AuthenticationEntryPoint> map = Maps.newLinkedHashMap();
    map.put(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/basic/**"), new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint());
    map.put(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/cert/**"), new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint());

    final DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint(map);
    entryPoint.setDefaultEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"));

    return entryPoint;
}
```

And my `configure`

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    defaultConfig(http)
            .headers()
            .contentTypeOptions()
            .xssProtection()
            .cacheControl()
            .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
            .addHeaderWriter(new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(SAMEORIGIN))
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .accessDecisionManager(decisionManager())
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(delegatingEntryPoint())
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);
}
```

Where `decisionManager()` returns a `UnanimousBased` instance. `sessionRegistry()` returns a `SessionRegistryImpl` instance. Both methods are `@Bean`.

I add a custom `UserDetailsService` using:

```
@Autowired
public void configureAuthManager(
        final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder,
        final InMemoryUserDetailsService authService) throws Exception {
    authBuilder.userDetailsService(authService);
}
```

And I have a custom `FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource` mapped using a `BeanPostProcessor` as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8387395/2071828).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chaining multiple entry points won't really work.

Your best option here might be to just customize the form-login process to check for the certificate if it's needed (before authenticating the user). That would probably simplify the configuration overall. It would really just be the same as a normal form-login setup.

The work done by the X509 filter [is quite minimal](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/x509/X509AuthenticationFilter.java#L16). So for example, you could override the [`attemptAuthentication`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java#L71) method, call `super.attemptAuthentication()` and then check that the certificate information matches the returned user authentication information.